# UI Bootstrap checkbox and radio slow on ipad

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

Trying to implement Checkbox and Radio buttons from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ but it is very slow (about a second) to react.

Is there something I can do to make it react more quickly? Or another library that does the same thing more reliably?

---

### EDIT: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/zrMxL/show) ... and [jsFiddle source](http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/zrMxL)

The demo loads bootstrap ui, and fastclick, which is initialised in one area and not the other. You can see the input fields behave as expected - fast with fastclick, slow without. The toggle buttons behave slowly everywhere.

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

function EditingPageCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.radioModelA = undefined;
    $scope.radioModelB = undefined;
    $scope.fast1 = "this field works quickly, because of fastclick...";
    $scope.fast2 = "this field is slow, because no fastclick";
    $scope.$watch('radioModelA', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        //alert(newValue);    
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you set the viewport? This sounds like the 300ms touch delay issue.

Comment: Are you using ngTouch which has it's own implementation of fastclick http://labs.ft.com/articles/ft-fastclick/ and will reduce this 300ms delay?

Comment: @APAD1 it could be 300ms delay issue, but to be honest, feels more like a second delay than 300ms.

Comment: @JonSamwell I have the issue in my own app, but I am also experiencing from their own website, so expected it is not a problem with my own implementation. Perhaps I will make a jsfiddle to demo the issue, and try to fix it there.

Comment: Add the link here an I will look too.  Are you sure if not just a really big watch cycle executing when you click/touch the checkbox?

Comment: @JonSamwell I added the fiddle - could you take a look? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally, the `btn-radio` directive is attaching a click handler via JavaScript. FastClick doesn't hijack the touch event and trigger a click because **FastClick *doesn't* support labels**. Here is the btnRadio source:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.buttons', [])

  .constant('buttonConfig', {
    activeClass:'active',
    toggleEvent:'click'
  })

  .directive('btnRadio', ['buttonConfig', function (buttonConfig) {
  var activeClass = buttonConfig.activeClass || 'active';
  var toggleEvent = buttonConfig.toggleEvent || 'click';

  return {

    require:'ngModel',
    link:function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

      var value = scope.$eval(attrs.btnRadio);

      //model -> UI
      scope.$watch(function () {
        return ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
      }, function (modelValue) {
        if (angular.equals(modelValue, value)){
          element.addClass(activeClass);
        } else {
          element.removeClass(activeClass);
        }
      });

      //ui->model
      element.bind(toggleEvent, function () {
        if (!element.hasClass(activeClass)) {
          scope.$apply(function () {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(value);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
}])
```

---

### Solution 1

**ngTouch** hooks into the `ng-click` directive. So... it's a little janky, but if you use **ngTouch** instead of FastClick, **you can get improved performance by adding an `ng-click` attribute**:

```
 <label ng-model="radioModelA" ng-click="radioModelA=true" btn-radio="true" class="btn btn-silver">Yes</label>
 <label ng-model="radioModelA" ng-click="radioModelA=false" btn-radio="false" class="btn btn-silver">No</label>
```

---

### Solution 2

A more elegant solution is to **inject `btn-radio`'s configuration constant and add a touch event**:

```
.config(function(buttonConfig) {
    buttonConfig.toggleEvent = 'touchstart click';
});
```

---

### Solution 3

Use **`<button>`** elements instead of **`<label>`s** and you can use either **FastClick** or **ngTouch** to avoid the mobile browser delay.

---

**Also [check this out: the vanilla ui-bootstrap demo seems faster than yours, because of the way that it's styled](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview).**

Comment: Solution 3 worked great. Never occurred to me that fastclick is picky about the elements it operates on, but it makes a lot of sense actually.